# Preorder traversal visualization of binary tree

Tags: c++, sdl, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I've decided to take the code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#C.2B.2B and visualize it using SDL. The ASCII graphic on the page looks like:

```
         1
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     2       3
    / \     /
   4   5   6
  /       / \
 7       8   9
```

But the result I've managed to get so far looks like:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/x0ts7m.png]

ASCII:

```
        1
      2 
    4   3
  7   6
    8
      9
```

Note the missing 5. The 6 is drawn on top of it (verified by debug output of positions.)

And my problem code:

In response to pointing out the typo, I'll copy/paste from my source file exactly as it is:

```
  void preorderTraverse(int x = osd.position.x, int y = osd.position.y) const {
    osd.position.x = x;
    osd.position.y = y;
    std::cout << "Debug: " << x << " " << y << " " << getValue() << std::endl;
    osd.put(getValue());
    if(mLeft)  {  x -= 50; y += 30; mLeft->preorderTraverse(x, y);}
    if(mRight) {  x += 50; y += 30; mRight->preorderTraverse(x, y);}
  }
```

The idea is that it follows the recursive nature of the traversal, but it seems to be problematic when it traverses the right side.

Note that I set the default parameters as osd.position because they're defined like this:

```
position.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 50/2;
position.y = 0;
```

And osd.put is:

```
SDL_Rect offset = get_offset(num);

SDL_BlitSurface( number_chart_, &offset, screen, &position );
```

offset is the source rectangle (i.e., blitting an image.) get_offset simply slices a sprite sheet of numbers.

So my question is how can I fix preorderTraverse to look like the ascii graphic? It doesn't have to do complicated things like check the width of the whole tree, etc., just be nested properly.

Comment: Is that your real code?  `x -= graphicWidth` for **both** `mLeft` **and** `mRight`?

Comment: I don't know how that typo got there, but it's not present in my source file. The image I got is built from the source file without the typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple bug in your code. For the right child, you should **add** to `x` and not subtract from it. That is, you should do this:

```
if(mRight) 
{
    x += graphicWidth; // <-- Note the "+" here.
    y += graphicHeight; 
    mRight->preorderTraverse(x, y);
}
```

But this will *not* fix all your problems. I think the amount that you add or subtract to/from `x` on each recursion should depend on the depth you are at in the tree.

As an example of what you can do, try the following. Add another parameter to `preorderTraverse` called `xstride`, like so:

```
void preorderTraverse(int xstride, int x, int y) const
```

and initialize it like this on the first call:

```
preorderTraverse (SCREEN_WIDTH / 4, /*some value for X*/, /*some value for Y*/)
```

then, in the function body, you add/subtract `xstride` to/from `x`:

```
x += xstride; // or x -= xstride. Also see the end note.
```

and on each recursive call to `preorderTraverse`, you divide `xstride` by 2:

```
mLeft->preorderTraverse (xstride / 2, x, y); // or mRight->...
```

Note: you probably need to add `graphicWidth` to `xstride` when adding/subtracting it to/from `x`.

Comment: The typo got there when I was transferring my code to the question. I replaced 50 with graphicWidth and accidentally added the typo. I still have the problem.

Comment: OK. Try out the rest of my answer, and see if that helps. I'll remove the now-redundant parts of the answer.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code sample? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is simply wrong here.

```
if(mLeft)  {  x -= 50; y += 30; mLeft->preorderTraverse(x, y);}
if(mRight) {  x += 50; y += 30; mRight->preorderTraverse(x, y);}
```

Look at it and think what happens to `x` if **both** `mLeft` **and** `mRight` exist.  You subtract 50 *and then add it back*.  `mRight` ends up with the same x coordinate as the parent.

Likewise with `y` you're adding 30 **twice**.

You wanted something like this.

```
if(mLeft)  {  mLeft->preorderTraverse(x - 50, y + 30);}
if(mRight) {  mRight->preorderTraverse(x + 50, y + 30);}
```